# Dynamic ratingValue for AggregateRating

Tags: html, schema.org, rating, dynamic-content

I am currently adding `AggregateRating` to our website so that the rating stars for our company appear in the search results. I proceeded as follows:

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EducationalOrganization">
...
    <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
      <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1">
      <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5">
      <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4,6">
      <meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="19">
    </div> 
... 
</body>
```

Apart from the fact that I use invisible meta-tags, which are not sure whether they are read out by Google, I am thinking about the following "problem":

The values ​​for `ratingValue`, and `reviewCount` are static here, which are simply entered by hand. Should not they be dynamic or is there a way to insert them dynamically? Or do they always have to be maintained and updated by hand?

The values ​​to be displayed are based on our Google Reviews.

Comment: Nothing special here, it can work like in every other case with dynamic content, too: you let applications on your server do the work ([PHP example](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/110150/17633)). -- Do you ask how dynamic HTML content can be possible in general? Or do you ask how you can extract the Google Reviews data?

Comment: @unor I want to know how to dynamically get the Google Reviews values ​​into my website. There are many documentation describing adding AggregateRating, but they are all non-dynamic. Does Google want dynamic values ​​here at all or rather that everything is entered statically by hand?

Comment: Search engines have no way of knowing if you enter the data manually or automatically on the server-side. The result is a HTML file; how it got generated/created is your secret. -- It’s different if you generate it on the client-side with JavaScript (everyone can see the `script`), but this might not be supported for Google's rich results if you use Microdata.

Comment: @unor So for my understanding: If something changes on our google rating, then I have to manually transfer the changes to my template. So here's no way to work with variables (supplied by Google)?

Comment: No, there might be a way (either officially supported by Google Reviews, e.g., an API, or your own solution to scrape the data) -- I was only saying that a search engine doesn’t know *how* you include the data in your HTML. -- If your question is how to get the data from Google Reviews, it would make sense to [edit] your question and the title to reflect this.